# Why is my discord bot not sending messages?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My discord bot is not sending any messages, when I type `+hi`, nothing responds. Although, it is sending the message when it's turned on. When I type `+hi`, nothing happens.

[image: When the bot is turned on, it sends the message]
[image: it's not doing anything]

Here is my code.

```js
// - Discord Requires
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '+';
// - Imports
const date = require('date-and-time');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require("express")();
// - Embed
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
// - Logo
const logo = './images/logo.png'
// - On Start
client.once('ready', () =>{
  //- Status and Conlole log Message
  client.user.setPresence({activity: {name:"Counting-Days", type:'WATCHING'}, status:'online'})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("I'm ready, from now on I'm gonna count Christmas Days!:)");
  }, 2000);
  // - Current Date and Time
  const now_date = new Date();
  date.format(now_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
  date.format(now_date, 'ddd, MMM DD YYYY');
  date.format(now_date, 'hh:mm A [GMT]Z');
  date.format(now_date, 'hh:mm A [GMT]Z', true);
  // - Makes the pattern for time
  const time_pattern = date.compile('hh:mm A');
  const time = date.format(now_date, time_pattern);
  const date_pattern = date.compile('ddd, MMM DD YYYY')
  const date_a = date.format(now_date, date_pattern);
  // - Channel Message => Ready
  client.channels.cache.get('935621866926768159').send(`**Christmas Countdown Bot** is awake |Date: **${date_a}**, Time: **${time}**| and waiting to reply to |${prefix}| commands!✅`)
});

// - Calculates the Days until Christmas (25/12/2022)
const newYears = "25 Dec 2022";

const newYearsDate = new Date(newYears);
const currentDate = new Date();

const totalSeconds = (newYearsDate - currentDate) / 1000;
const days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600 / 24);
const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600) % 24;
const mins = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
const seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds) % 60;

client.on("message", function (message){
  if (message.content === `${prefix}hi`){
    message.channel.send(`Hey, ${days}`);
  }
})
// -Token
client.login('TOKEN')
```

I've tried restarting the bot several times but it didn't work.
I also tried the code on another bot and it worked.

Comment: Your _code_ appears to be one big [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Are you sure you've got the formatting right?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If so, include them in your post

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely lies on your message function. Discord.js has replaced the old `client.on("message...` and replaced it with `client.on("messageCreate...`.

You've done:

```js
client.on("message", function (message){
  if (message.content === `${prefix}hi`){
    message.channel.send(`Hey, ${days}`);
  }
})
```

The correct way to do this is as follows:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", function (message) => {
  if(message.content === `${prefix}hi`){
    return message.channel.send(`Hey, ${days}`);
  };
})
```

It is likely that you've got two bots with different versions of discord.js, the older discord.js@v13 works with the `.on("message)` and gives a deprecation error in the console while the newer discord.js@v14 completely ignores the `.on("message")` as it is no longer an event.

Simply delete the incorrect event listener and replace it with the correct one.

It would be better if you had given a discord.js version to help the community understand your problem more.